# How do I define cyclical structs across modules and files in Rust?

Tags: rust

When I write

```rust
struct A { b : Option<B> }
struct B { a : Option<A> }
```

it compiles.

How would I split this up across modules and files?

When I try

```rust
// a.rs
mod b;
struct A { b : Option<B> }
```

```rust
// b.rs
mod a;
struct B { a : Option<A> }
```

I get

```
$ rustc a.rs 
a.rs:1:5: 1:6 error: circular modules: b.rs -> a.rs -> b.rs
a.rs:1 mod b;
           ^
```

Here is my environment

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 0.11-pre-nightly (168b2d1 2014-04-14 14:36:54 -0700)
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
$ uname -a
Linux 3.14.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr 14 20:40:47 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being caught by incorrect usage of `mod`.

`mod` *defines* a module.

`use` imports an *already defined* module.

What you should be using is something like your `lib.rs` or `mod.rs` or whatever containing `mod a;` and `mod b;`, and then, in `a.rs`, `use b::B;`, and in `b.rs`, `use a::A`.

Comment: I think they say "changes visibility" rather than "imports" for the `use` item.

Comment: @ryantm: no, it's nothing to do with changing visibility; it's to do with making the item available in the current scope. Mostly that's just a shortcut (you could, for example, use `::a::A` everywhere instead of the `A` that you can write if you have `use a::A;`), but it's also important (at least at present, can't say whether it will change or not) in method resolution with traits (to call a method on a trait implementation, you must `use` the trait).